# Python showing local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've declared 2 variables the same exact way, but when I'm calling them stack is being referenced fine. But python is not able to reference top. What is the issue here?

```
def isValid(s):
    top=-1
    stack=[-1]*10005

    def push(x):
        print(top)
        top+=1
        stack[top]=x
    push()
```

print(isValid(input()))

Comment: This question was asked before, but the answer was never accepted - it is however the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323757/why-does-python-3-8-0-allow-to-change-mutable-types-from-enclosing-function-scop

Comment: top is immutable where as stack is mutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Python 3.8.0 allow to change mutable types from enclosing function scope without using "nonlocal" variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323757/why-does-python-3-8-0-allow-to-change-mutable-types-from-enclosing-function-scop)

Comment: @Grismar, I'm curious, if you think the other question has a correct answer, and you're even mentioning it here, why didn't you upvote it? Besides that's what the voting system is intended for, it allows this question to be flagged as duplicate as well.

Comment: @Edward, can you please fix the code and indentation? The code you posted has multiple errors (besides the one you're question is about). I would fix the indentation myself, but I'm not sure I can do that without changing the intended meaning of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is mostly correct.  Python considers any variable that you directly change the value of to be a local variable.  Since you write `top += 1`, `top` is directly modified inside `push`, and is a local variable to `push`.  The variable `stack`, on the other hand, is not changed.

I consider the fact that Python considers `+=` operators to cause a variable to become local to be a bit of a bug.  But it's too ingrained in the language.

And yes, the correct solution is to use `nonlocal`.

If you removed the `top += 1` line, your code wouldn't work, but `top` would refer to the outer variable.

Comment: You're wrong though: " += operators to cause a variable to become local" - that's not the case. If the function only contained `top += 1`, it would still be a problem.

Comment: I should add.  Before `nonlocal` was added to the language, there was a hack to get around this issue.  You would make `top` be a singleton list rather than just an integer.  `top = [-1]`.  `top[0] += 1`.  `stack[top[0]] = x`.  Ugly, but it means that the variable `top` itself wasn't modified, and so didn't become local to `push`.

Comment: @Grismar.  I don't understand what you're disagreeing with.  If a function contains `top += 1`, then `top` is a local variable in that function (barring `nonlocal`, `global`, etc).  What is your issue with that statement?

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, however although for `top += 1` to work, `top` must be local, it doesn't *become* local - if all the function contained was `top += 1`, it would still throw an error (but for a slightly different reason). `top` would still have to be assigned prior to the increment. So, I feel your explanation is very much open to misinterpretation and likely wouldn't be understood from OP's perspective.

Comment: @Grismar.  I still don't understand the distinction you're making.  If the code simply contained `top += 1`, the user would get an error indicating that the variable `top` is not defined.  The reason the variable `top` is not defined is because it is local, and so the function can't access the outer definition.  The reason it is local is because of the `top += 1`.  I think that Python made a mistake in having `top += 1`, in the absence of any other assignment to `top`, create a local variable, but that boat sailed years ago.  I still don't get what you're disagreeing with.

Comment: You should probably focus on what I actually said. You wrote "Python considers += operators to cause a variable to become local" - that's simply not the case. The `+=` operator requires a "local" (or more correctly a pre-existing and accessible) variable to operate on - it does nothing to actually change the nature of the variable to comply with that need. That's what `global` and `nonlocal` are for. Nothing is causing anything to become local unless you actually add a statement that does so - hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because `push` is indented inside `isValid`, it can't change the value of `top` from its "parent" function.

You can use `nonlocal`:

```
def isValid(s):
    top=-1
    stack=[-1]*10005

    def push(x):
        nonlocal top
        print(top)
        top+=1
        stack[top]=x
```

Comment: In that case, why is push(x) able to reference stack?

Comment: Because internally you're accessing a method of `stack`, not changing its value.

Comment: The question asks why `stack` *is* visible inside `push()`, while `top` is not - your answer doesn't address that.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in how you access the variable, which causes it to be treated differently. Consider this:

```
def isValid():
    top = -1

    def push():
        print(top)

    push()


isValid()
```

Here there is no error, since `top` can be found in the scope of `isValid()` and calling `push()` will print it correctly. However, if you add `top += 1`, Python correctly infers that `top` apparently has to be a local variable for that to work, but it isn't, so now `top` is showing as problematic everywhere inside `push()` (in most IDEs).

```
def isValid():
    top = -1

    def push():
        print(top)  # you'll see error messages / highlighting for top here
        top += 1  # and here as well

    push()


isValid()
```

Note that `top += 1` isn't even the first statement, but its presence causes `print(top)` to no longer work either, since `top` now has to be local. But since there's no assignment to `top` before the other two statements, Python will correctly complain that it has been accessed before having been assigned.

The reason this doesn't happen with your `stack` is that you're not actually trying to change `stack` inside `push()`. You're trying to change one of its elements (`stack[1]`), but that doesn't change what object `stack` is naming - you're not assigning to `stack` itself, so it does not become local.

So, Python finds `stack` in the scope of `isValid`, allows you to access it (just like `top` in the first example) and you can access its elements without issue.

Answer (score 0):

top is pointing to a literal hence it is immutable and stack is a mutable object if you wanted to solve the problem with top which is not actually a problem, you have 2 options.

1. create a copy of top in push
2. use a mutable object

example:

1. nonlocal top
2. top = {'value': -1 }

case: 1

```
def isValid(s):
top=-1
stack=[-1]*10005

def push(x):
    nonlocal top
    print(top)
    top+=1
    stack[top]=x
```

case 2:

```
def isValid(s):
    top= {'value': -1}
    stack=[-1]*10005

def push(x):
    print(top)
    top['value']+=1
    stack[top]=x
```